# How to translate that a financial asset has "priced in" an event or news?

Tags: translation

I'd guess "計入", as in 事件已計入. 金融資產有已經計入事件.

[What Is ‘Priced In’? - WSJ](https://www.wsj.com/articles/what-is-priced-in-11588427033)

> What do investors mean when they use the phrase “It’s priced in”? They’re talking about the way investors’ expectations move financial markets.
>
> “It’s Wall Street’s fancy way of saying ‘anticipated,’ ” says Adam Johnson, founder and author of the Bullseye Brief financial newsletter. He gives the hypothetical example of a 14-year-old taking the family car for a drive without permission. “If you take a joy ride in your parents’ car at that age you will anticipate, or price in, the disappointment from your parents when you walk back in the front door,” he says.
>
> In financial markets, anticipation is a driving force. Investors look at likely future events to adjust how much they are willing to pay for stocks or other assets. “If you anticipate bad news next week, then you sell the stock this week,” Mr. Johnson says. And if investors anticipate good news, many buy.
>
> In general, new information quickly gets reflected in financial-market prices, giving us a sense of what investors as a whole are thinking about the future for business and the economy. But of course that sentiment can reverse quickly as new information becomes available.
> [What does 'priced in' mean in stock trading? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-priced-in-mean-in-stock-trading)

> [Sofien Kaabar](https://www.quora.com/profile/Sofien-Kaabar) , Institutional FX Strategist | Trader | Cleared CFA level 3
> [Answered July 11, 2020](https://www.quora.com/What-does-priced-in-mean-in-stock-trading/answer/Sofien-Kaabar) · Author has 882 answers and 911.6K answer views

> Priced-in means that the current or upcoming news event / economic release is already reflected in the current prices. In other words, there will be no strong movement after the release of the new information because most market participants have adjusted their positions accordingly and thus the powers of supply and demand are relatively in equilibrium.

I embold "priced in" in one book. I'll add more examples if time permits.

Lasse Heje Pedersen. *Efficiently Inefficient How Smart Money Invests and Market Prices Are Determined* (2015). p 247.

> ### What Yield Changes Are Already Priced In? Forward Rates

> Fixed-income investors often have a sense of the direction of interest rates.
> For instance, if the short-term interest rate is already at zero, chances are that
> it will be rising. Does this mean that one should sell short on bonds? Not necessarily,
> because bond yields already reflect this expectation, at least to some
> extent. You should only sell short on bonds if you think that bond yields will
> rise faster or further than what is **priced in**. How do you know what is **priced
> in**, though?

Comment: 计入 is not the Mandarin, Chinese people would say this word.

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a catchy phrase, and am bereft of financial knowledge. Maybe this might help a bit:

The asset price anticipates upcoming financial market events.
这个资产价格已经预示了金融市场即将发生的改变。

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> 资产的价格已经考虑进了某事件的影响

or you can say:

> 资产价格已经计入某事件的影响

Answer (score 1):

It seems that no single word can express this phrase made by investors.

計入, I think, may not appropriate, and it sounds like `account` 记账.

Perhaps, 影响, 已经影响了预期 (has affected the expectation);
已经纳入考虑 (has been considered), despite the single 纳入 is also not appropriate, I believe it must relate some noun like 考虑/预期, to express clearly.

計入考虑 sounds okay too (it sounds really formal and serious).

( the answer only for simplified Chinese lang (in mainland).